# Sort array by value leaving key value intact

Tags: php

I am looking through the PHP array sorting functions to find some way to do the following but can't seem to manage it.

Example

```
Array ( 
[77] => 79
[72] => 78
[71] => 78
[82] => 79
[76] => 79
[73] => 78
[75] => 78 )
```

and I want to re order it to

```
Array ( 
[72] => 78
[71] => 78
[73] => 78
[75] => 78
[77] => 79
[82] => 79
[76] => 79 )
```

notice the way the key's respect the order they were originally in they are just arranged according to the value ( so that 77 which was first in 79 is still first in 79 etc )

I thought aasort would work but it didn't

```
asort($categories);
foreach ($categories as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key = $val\n";
    echo "<br>";
}
```

output ( please pardon the equals sign )

```
74 = 78
85 = 78
75 = 78
73 = 78
70 = 78
71 = 78
72 = 78
82 = 79
86 = 79
81 = 79
77 = 79
80 = 79
76 = 79
```

Comment: assort() guarantees order by value and retention of key, but makes no guarantee that multiple keys with the same value will be ordered in any particular manner

Comment: A Quicksort is algorithm isn't conducive to handling this because elements aren't processed sequentially by the sort; you may need to implement something like a bubble sort or a merge sort manually

Comment: is there a certain reason you need them in that particular order?

Comment: @BrianGlaz just that I have them in order and I don't want the order messed up. The values in this case are parents and the keys are children ( weird I know but that's how it is). I need to sort by parent and keep the sort order that the children were already in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably possible to integrate this into some implementation of bubble sort as Mark suggests, but there will be a trade-off in speed. If speed is not an issue to begin with, here is a naive implementation that does what you want.

It simply keeps count on which keys were used for a particular value and then makes sure the final sorted array honours that order:

```
function sort_keys_intact(&$a) {
    $b = array();
    $values = array();
    foreach ( $a as $k => $v ) {
        $values[$v][] = $k;
    }
    asort($a);
    $used = 0;
    foreach ( $a as $k => $v ) {
        if ( $used == count($values[$v]) + 1 ) {
            $used = 0;
        }
        $b[$values[$v][$used]] = $v;
        $used++;
    }
    $a = $b;
}
```

*Test run*:

```
echo 'Before:' . PHP_EOL;
print_r($categories);
sort_keys_intact($categories);
echo 'After:' . PHP_EOL;
print_r($categories);
```

*Output*:

```
Before:
Array
(
    [77] => 79
    [72] => 78
    [71] => 78
    [82] => 79
    [76] => 79
    [73] => 78
    [75] => 78
)
After:
Array
(
    [72] => 78
    [71] => 78
    [73] => 78
    [75] => 78
    [77] => 79
    [82] => 79
    [76] => 79
)
```

Comment: Speed is completely not an issue here at all, and never will be. The function worked perfectly thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with PHP so not sure how you'd do it in PHP (perhaps thats the problem) but you could create a second list that looks like this:

```
[77] => (79,1)
[72] => (78,2)
[71] => (78,3)
[82] => (79,4)
[76] => (79,5)
[73] => (78,6)
[75] => (78,7)
```

This is a tuple with the original value and the order value. Do a sort, then remove the ordering for each, to produce the desired format.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
function my_sort(&$array)
{
  $i = 0;
  foreach ($array as &$val)
    $val = [$i++, $val];

  uasort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return $a[1] - $b[1] ?: $a[0] - $b[0];
  });

  foreach ($array as &$val)
    $val = $val[1];
}
```

Which I think is simply an implementation of @Nuclearman's answer.

This assumes all values are integers. If that's not the case, you'd have to change the `$a[1] - $b[1]` to reflect how the values should be sorted. (If values are same, then the sort function return `$a[0] - $b[0]`.)

Answer (score 0):

the answers didnt worked for me so i wrote a function of my one to solve this issue:

```
function sort_value_leave_key(&$arr){

$z = array();
foreach ($arr as $k => $v){
    $z[$v.rand(1111,9999)] = $k;
}
krsort($z);

$arr = array();
foreach($z as $k => $v){
    $arr[$v] = substr($k,0,-4);
}

}
```